# Error while upgrading django cms to 3.5 migration of "cms.0018_pagenode" stops saying Cannot resolve keyword 'title_set' into field

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-cms

I am trying to upgrade an existing project from django-cms 3.4 to 3.5.
I have Django 1.8 and while migrating at some point it stops giving an error : django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'title_set' into field.

in the documentation for 3.5 they have this sentence:
Never-published pages can no longer have a ‘pending’ publishing state. A data migration, cms/migrations/0018_pagenode.py, removes this.

my problem seems to be related to this. Can somebody helm me with that? I don't get it.

```sh
Applying cms.0017_pagetype... OK
  Applying cms.0018_pagenode...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 110, in migrate
    self.apply_migration(states[migration], migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 115, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/special.py", line 181, in database_forwards
    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms/migrations/0018_pagenode.py", line 38, in unpublish_never_published_pages
    publisher_public__isnull=True,
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 679, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 697, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1301, in add_q
    clause, require_inner = self._add_q(where_part, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1328, in _add_q
    current_negated=current_negated, connector=connector, allow_joins=allow_joins)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1144, in build_filter
    lookups, parts, reffed_aggregate = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1030, in solve_lookup_type
    _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())
  File "/home/project_folder/.venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1386, in names_to_path
    "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'title_set' into field. Choices are: application_namespace, application_urls, changed_by, changed_date, created_by, creation_date, depth, fibre_check_ko, fibre_check_ok, id, in_navigation, is_home, is_page_type, languages, limit_visibility_in_menu, login_required, navigation_extenders, numchild, parent, parent_id, path, placeholders, publication_date, publication_end_date, publisher_is_draft, publisher_public, publisher_public_id, reverse_id, revision_id, site, site_id, soft_root, template, xframe_options

Fatal error: local() encountered an error (return code 1) while executing 'python manage.py migrate'

Aborting.
```

Comment: Django 1.8 has been end of life since April 2018, and doesn't receive security updates any more. You should upgrade to Django 1.11 LTS, then upgrade to Django 2.2 LTS once your project supports Python 3. Until you can upgrade, switch to the latest minor version, 1.8.19, so that you get the latest security patches. This will should also fix your error when you run migrate.

Comment: @Alasdair I did it. Upgraded to django 1.9 and got rid of that problem, but I had a thousand other problems to solve. Now it is Ok. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to upgrade to Django 1.9 to fix the error, the latest 1.8.X will do. Once that's solved, you should upgrade to at least Django 1.11.X, because Django 1.8, 1.9 and 1.10 are all unsupported.